# Why does this repeating command block think I am not in range?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have this code:

```
tell @a[name=mpboom,r=2] hey
```

In a command block with this properties:

```
Repeat - Unconditional - Always Active
```

My name is mpboom. But if I come close, within the 2-block radius, it will do nothing.

Is my computer bugged, is the game bugged, or is my code wrong?

I am playing on Vanilla Minecraft 1.10.2 on Windows. It is in Singleplayer.

For anyone who does not understand yet, I want to make this command block say 'hey' ONLY to me (mpboom) if I am in a radius of two blocks.

Thank you!

Comment: Try putting `/say Test` into the command block and see if anything happens. It may be that the command block is not running.

Comment: I did /tell test (that is the same right?) and it gave just the output you would expect.

Comment: Do you have the leading `/` in the command block?  I have a feeling that's required now.

Comment: The output I'd expect for "`/tell test`" is for that not to work because of invalid syntax. Try `/say Test`, or `/tell @a Test`.

Comment: @MBraedley The `/` is optional in command blocks.

Comment: You are right, colorfusion, i did put the @a in it while testing, just forgot to type it here. @MBreadly, yes, tried it with and without the /.

Comment: @mpboom And what happened when you did that?

Comment: Just worked, so i think the command block is running...

Comment: @mpboom Is there any output (box below command input) in the command block when you get near it?

Comment: No just the '-' (what you get when you just placed it).

Comment: @mpboom Is the button to the right of the output an O or an X?

Comment: @mpboom Click it to change it to O, go near the command block then see if there's any output in the output box.

Comment: Everything the same, the only thing I changed was the 'O'. Now the output bar is gone and still nothing.

Comment: @mpboom Are you on a server or using any mods? Is your in-game name exactly `mpboom` (case-sensitive)? Try `tell @a a`, `tell @a[r=2] b`, then `tell @a[name=mpboom] c` and see which ones work to try to narrow down what's causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I fixed it while trying to narrow it down! I will post the answer below! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was approaching the command block from beneath. You have to be above the command block or it would not detect you with the r=2 selector. I think this might have something to do with that I was standing with my feet on the ground and the r=2 looks at where your feet are.

Comment: I will accept it, I just have to wait 8 more hours...